# google charts: google is not defined

Tags: firefox, google-api, google-visualization

I am trying to use the google charts on firefox, the problem is the google api is not loaded successfully on firefox only `ReferenceError: google is not defined`

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    function LoadGoogle(){
        if(typeof google != 'undefined' && google && google.load){
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

              // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
              google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

              // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
              // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
              // draws it.
              function drawChart() {

            // Create the data table.
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
            data.addRows([
              ['Mushrooms', 3],
              ['Onions', 1],
              ['Olives', 1],
              ['Zucchini', 1],
              ['Pepperoni', 2]
            ]);

            // Set chart options
            var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                           'width':400,
                           'height':300};

            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("try");
            setTimeout(LoadGoogle, 30);
        }
    }

    LoadGoogle();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**first**, remove the reference to `jsapi`, as stated in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

**next**, remove the "validation" `if` statement from `LoadGoogle`, this shouldn't be needed and would need to change due to removing `jsapi`

the following snippet works for me in Firefox ESR, v: 45.3.0

```js
function LoadGoogle(){
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawChart,
    packages:['corechart']
  });

  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}

LoadGoogle();
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanx @whiteHat - <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script> help me out

Answer (score -1):

You have to copy the URL https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js and put the url in the browser, click right and save as file.js save the both files in your project, just make a referneces the files in your html